# How to find some words in previously read lines and delete it in output- read/write strings in c++

Tags: c++, string, file

I am reading a text file in c++ and writing a bunch of paired numbers from it to another file.

The structure of input file is a bunch of paired numbers and some lines like "remove120 43 blah bla" that indicates removing one of the previous paired numbers, in this case 120 43( that surely exists in one of the previous lines).

So, each time there is a word "remove" in a line, i want to find its paired numbers in the previous lines and delete it from my output.

P.S. I have provided this input file in past, but I am not good in working with strings at this point which makes this confusion for me.

I started like this:

```
string s;
ifstream myfile("input.txt");
ofstream output ("output.txt");

if(myfile.is_open()){
    while (!myfile.eof()){
        getline (myfile, s);
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some code would be helpful to see where you're at currently, but from what you've described I'd set up something like this:

```
istream file;
string line;
map pairs;
sstream line_parser;
int one, two

while (file >> line) {
    line_parser.str(line);
    if (line[0] == 'r') {
       line_parser >> line; // take 'remove' out of the stream
       line_parser >> one;
       pairs.erase(pairs.find(one));
    } else {
       line_parser >> one;
       line_parser >> two;
       pairs[one] = two;
    }
}
```

Edit:
   This assumes you won't have duplicate keys, otherwise the values will be overwritten.  Any container can be substituted for the map to hold the pairs

Comment: thanks for your answer. It seems great to me, however I have trouble understanding istream and sstream here and also using maps, which I will somehow figure them out. Thanks again.

Comment: sorry, istream should have been ifstream, sstream is another std stream object for dealing with strings in memory.  In this case it's extracting words and integers from the line read from the file.  As for the map, I just picked it for the simple key referencing, a vector could be easily substituted.

Comment: +1 for showing many relevant techniques.  That said, I can't see anything in the question suggesting the pairs are key/value.  Hard to suggest an implementation as the question doesn't say whether the order of output needs to match the order of input.  If not, then a `std::set<std::pair<int,int>>` seems good and is close to what you've done.  `sstream` should be `stringstream` though (the former's the containing header), and while there's no `operator[]` `peek()` should work as you intend.  If order's important, then `vector` with an optional index to avoid repeated linear searches....